# Unable to start cordova ionic project : Unable to load Maven Meta-Data in VS2015

Tags: android, cordova, maven, visual-studio-2015, ionic-framework

I am very new to mobile development and am trying to get head start in cordova Ionic project in VS2015. I installed all the necessary components and started a new project of type ionic tabbed template (which I got from NuGet). Upon compiling the project I got into the error given below and am not able to bypass this. Any help is welcome.

PS: I am working behind corporate proxy.

```
                    Running: C:\Development\CordovaIonicDemo\CordovaIonicDemoUI\platforms\android\gradlew clean -b C:\Development\CordovaIonicDemo\CordovaIonicDemoUI\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
1>                     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
1>                     * What went wrong: (TaskId:6)
1>                     A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. (TaskId:6)
1>                     > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. (TaskId:6)
1>                        > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+. (TaskId:6)
1>                          Required by: (TaskId:6)
1>                              :android:unspecified (TaskId:6)
1>                           > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle. (TaskId:6)
1>                              > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml. (TaskId:6)
1>                                 > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'. (TaskId:6)
1>                                    > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
1>                     * Try: (TaskId:6)
1>                     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
1>                     BUILD FAILED (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
1>                     Total time: 2.536 secs (TaskId:6)
1>                     Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M (TaskId:6)
1>                      (TaskId:6)
```

Comment: The problem is the corporate proxy. You need to configure npm so that it uses your proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks Michael, However I am facing this issue because I am not able to navigate to https ://repo1.maven.org, though I can navigate to http ://repo1.maven.org. Is there any setting where I can instruct npm or Gradle to download the dependencies from http address and not from https.

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the proxies being blocked here in my company Firewall, once those were opened everything is working good.

Comment: Cool, thanks, let me just open the Great Chinese Firewall.